# Pagination is broken after migrating from angular version 4 to version 10

Tags: angular, pagination, migration, ag-grid

After migrating from angular 4 to 10, Ag-grid `paginationGetPageSize()` method stopped accepting arguments to this method which was accepted in the previous versions. This broke the pagination functionality. Do we have any alternative method for `paginationGetPageSize()`, which accepts arguments and has the same functionality?

Comment: Did you make sure to upgrade the version of ag-grid you're using? Looking at their compatability chart I'd start by guessing your issue is there: https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid/getting-started/#ag-grid--angular-compatibility-chart

Comment: The current version of ag-grid that we use is 14.2.0 and we can go upto version 17,I Know v 24 of ag grid is the compatible version with Angular 10, but anything after v17 of ag-grid requires re-write of our entire application code. Since we have to finish it up quicker we cannot opt for a re-write for the code. So wanted to check if we have any other alternative method for paginationGetPageSize() which accepts arguments.

Comment: If their documentation says that you need x version for comparability with A10 then that’s what I’d go with. You might be able to get it to work but would take reverse engineering what has changed between v17 and v24. What it sounds like is you’re best off not upgrading to A10 at this moment, and should wait until you can appropriately update all the packages.